# Minha SQL Query não funciona corretamente?

Tags: php, mysql, query, pdo

Eu tenho um sistema que utiliza datas para registro e eu separo a data por um explode formado por arrays e registro elas em um banco, porém quando faço a query que busca elas por ordem, a ordem embaraça.

**Segue exemplos do código ->**

```
      <?php 
                    $listar = new USER();
     $stmt = $listar->runQuery("SELECT * FROM horario ORDER BY dia,mes,ano DESC LIMIT 5");
    $stmt->execute();
    $Row=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Datas recentes : 08/11/2018

[image: Pesquisa de Monitorias por data recente]

[image: Registros Banco de Dados MYSQL]

Como podem ver não esta pegando os registros como deveria, por favor preciso de ajuda é meu TCC!!!

Comment: Acho que é pq vc ta dando uma ordenação DESC só no ano. Tenta mudar para: ORDER BY dia DESC ,mes  DESC,ano DESC. Mas se vc fizesse um campo de date com a data por completo seria mais fácil pra vc tratar depois.

Comment: Lembre-se também q vc ta fazendo uma ordenação por data, onde tem datas iguais, mas não tem tempo de hora, para que o mysql saiba qual é o dado mais recente ou mais antigo. então ele continua a ordenação crescente pelos outros campos.  e talvez por isso vc esteja tendo esse embaralhamento.

Comment: Eu recentemente fiz uma tabela alternativa para registrar todos as datas,horários para uso do "Time Ago", porém somente isso, no caso eu salvo no banco sendo como dia, mês e ano pois não é só o site que alimenta o banco, tem mais 2 frentes ( Android, Desktop ) que também vão utilizar do banco e ficou mais fácil separar a data para eles( não sou eu que os faço ), mas seu exemplo do SELECT abaixo resolveu meu problema!! Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está fazendo uma ordenação crescente por dia e mes, e decrescente por apenas no ano.

Seus dados não tem uma ordem de hora, para que o mysql saiba qual é a data mais recente ou mais antiga, então acho que você pode resolver este problema com o ID, pegando pela ordem do id mais recente.

Acho que um select assim resolveria seu caso:

```
 SELECT * FROM horario ORDER BY ano DESC, mes DESC, dia DESC, idh DESC  LIMIT 5
```